# AngularJS - how to set css class for the custom directive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Have `tab` css class for the `nav` html element which I'm going to use as directive like this:

```
<nav tab></nav>
```

It expected to be interpreted like this:

```
<nav class="tab">
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
</nav>
```

... and everything works almost as expected except of the issue I cannot set the CSS class to the top `<nav>` element. Of course, I could specify it using `ng-class` explicitly but it seems to be not a great idea.

Have heard about `.addClass()` option but it doesn't work at all:

```
tab.directive('tab', function($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            templateUrl: 'nav-tab.html',
            controller: function($http, $scope) {
                $http.get('/Tab/List')
                    .success(function(data) {
                        $scope.tabs = data;
                    }).error(function() {
                        alert("error");
                    });
            },
            controllerAs: 'tab',
            link: function(element, scope) {
                angular.element(element).addClass('tab');
                $compile(element)(scope);
            }
        }
    });
```

How to add the CSS class to the top directive element without it's explicit specifying right at the element?

Comment: What's happening when you do `.addClass`? any error in console?

Comment: @PankajParkar, there's an empty Chrome console with the current code. If I use `.addClass()` as `element.addClass()` it says `.addClass is not a function`, I assume it occurs because there's no JQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a wrong sequence in link function

Instead of

```
link: function(element, scope) {
```

Change it to

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
```

Then you can directly do `element.addClass` as `jQLite` api has `.addClass` method available on it.

Comment: yeah it does work since I've switched to `element.addClass('tab')`. Thanks:)) 5mins to accept

Comment: Once you fix the above, you also don't need to wrap the element.

Answer (score 2):

I would change your directive to be an "element" ('E' instead of 'A' for attribute)

```
<tab></tab>

tab.directive('tab', function($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'nav-tab.html'...
```

and then add the class in your template **nav-tab.html**:

```
<nav class="tab">
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
</nav>
```

Comment: `replace: true` has been deprecated.. would not encourage to use it.. Without `replace: true` it would obviously work.